# Swift po causes error 'Failed to load linked library Metal'

Tags: swift, xcode6, lldb

How can I print out a Swift variable's value in XCode 6 GM with LLDB? It seems to be broken since early betas. But at the same time `po` works perfectly fine in Objective-C code

I've previously tried all XCode 6 betas and got the same result. Even when I start a new project from scratch it's all the same. For example, I put a breakpoint in `func application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)`

```
(lldb) po application
error: Error in auto-import:
Failed to load linked library Metal of module sandbox - errors:
Looking for "@rpath/Metal.framework/Metal", error: not a string object
```

I've never imported or linked against Metal.framework in any of my projects. Does there exist any way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, having the same problems.

Comment: +1... not encouraging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug was fixed in XCode 6.1

> **Resolved Issues - Debugging**
>
> Swift expressions like 'expr', 'p', and 'print' that are evaluated
>   from the LLDB prompt in the debugger console will now work on 32-bit
>   iOS devices. (18249931)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html

Answer (score 3):

Don't know the reason that **po** is broken in xCode 6, but I am able to print an object by

- Right clicking an object in the Debug Area
- and clicking -> Print Description of "OBJECT_NAME"

Hope this will help someone else, until the xCode bug is fixed

Answer (score 0):

[Metal.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalFrameworkReference/index.html) is a new framework provided by Apple in iOS8. Seems like AVFoundation has references to it. I think you getting this error running your app on iOS7 device or simulator. Try to check on iOS8.

Comment: Not using AVFoundation neither, the bug even appears in blank new projects, everywhere: on simulator, iOS7 devices and on OS X. It's weird, however, that most developers don't encounter that. WWDC Swift demos also had no such issues.